# Strange subdomain issue in NGINX

Tags: redirect, nginx, https, subdomain

What I want to do is:

- to redirect only `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` to https://domain.com
- to forward `subdomain.domain.com` and `domain.com` to the same directory
- to forward `backend.domain.com` to seperate directory

To get this job done I'm using configuration above. But it redirect all subdomains to `https://domain.com`. Tried with and without second server block of code (redirect block).

What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 443 default ssl;

    server_name domain.com *.domain.com;
    root        /var/www/frontend/web;
    index       index.php;

    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}   
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    domain.com www.domain.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name backend.domain.com;
    root        /var/www/backend/web;
    index       index.php;


    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks alright. Keep in mind that with a 301 (permanent) redirect, you should clear your browser cache to make sure a misconfiguration was not cached.